# Find/Replace Text in WebPage Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've created several .aspx templates that are displayed in an IFrame depending on main page selections. In the templates there are 20 - 30 words to be replaced, each one is different. I did this as opposed to putting a bunch of labels in there. Can I somehow find and replace the words on the template page load?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: You need a file-based search and replace tool. This is not a programming-related question.

Comment: I think he means that this is happening at runtime, so it is a programming question.

Comment: If they're aspx pages, I would place the content in a label or literal control, and then perform a string.replace. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Diodeus It is programming though. I am programatically loading page in an iframe and need to find and replace certain words with dimensions(as string) i.e. Replace("vertLen", "13.250") when the page loads.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, yes i think your right. Label or Literal is probably the only way to do it. If you create an answer then i can mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the content in a label or literal control, and then perform a string.replace. If you need more programmatic flexibility, you can use regex replacement, but you will get better performance from string.replace, even with very large strings. I can't find a cite, but that is my experience.